# If there a way to determine if a set of values contains a single instance of a string and create a new variable with only that string?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

My dataset looks like this

| Group | Requirement | Completion Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | RQ 1 | Complete |
| Group 1 | RQ 2 | Complete |
| Group 2 | RQ 3 | Complete |
| Group 2 | RQ 4 | Incomplete |

I want a variable that allows me to do do this

| Group | Completion Status |
| --- | --- |
| Group 1 | Complete |
| Group 2 | Incomplete |

Basically, I need a formula that can look at all of the Completion Status of the requirements which are related to the groups, so I can say "if any one of them are incomplete, the group is incomplete."

I have tried the following but it returns a #MULTIVALUE

```
=If(Match([Completion Status];"*Incomplete*"))  In([Group]) Then "Not Satisfied"
```